# Is it haram to eat food cooked by Christians for celebration of Christ?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, food

Is it Haram to eat Christmas food cooked by Christians?

I thought it might be haram because it was prepared for their celebration.

Comment: These kind of questions should already have answers on the site.

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed to *accept* gifts from non-Muslims on their festivals.

As for the food, it is allowed to accept and eat the food that has no meat in it and nothing else haram.

> 'ʻAli may Allaah be pleased with him was given a gift on the Nayrooz festival (Persian festival) and asked, 'What is this?' They replied, 'Oh, Leader of the Believers, today is Nayrooz day.' So he said, 'Then make every day Nayrooz.'" [Al-Bayhaqi: As-Sunan Al-Kubra]
>
> [*This gift was a type of sweet.*]

And a statement by Aisha (RA):

> A woman asked ‘Aa’ishah may Allaah be pleased with her "We have wet nurses from among the Magians, and they have a festival on which they bring us gifts?" ‘Aa’ishah said, "As for what is slaughtered for that day, do not eat it, but eat from their trees (i.e. vegetables and fruit)."  [Musannaf of Ibn Abi Shaybah]

Accepting gifts and eating food is good manners, and Allah says:

> and He does not forbid you to deal kindly and justly with anyone who has not fought you for your faith or driven you out of your homes: God loves the just. ([Quran 60:8](https://quran.com/60/8))

Comment: Maybe adding something regarding eating the meat of the people of Ahlu Kitab is surely relevant in regards to this question, even though there are different opinions.

Comment: @Kilise I didn't think it was relevant because the question is asking about whether it can be eaten in the context of their celebration. The assumption being that he already knows it is permissible in other contexts. But, I can definitely add it, if you think it might give more information.